# Как сделать чтобы в jar "увидел" при исполнении html-файл?

Tags: java, maven, resources, freemarker

Прописываю в `pom.xml`

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>templates/*.html</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

в jar попадает и папка templates и ее файл page.html.

вот так это реализовано в PageGenerator:

```
private static final String HTML_DIR = "templates";
Template template = cfg.getTemplate(HTML_DIR + File.separator + filename);
```

, где `cfg` объект класса `freemarker.template.Configuration`
Однако потом проверяющая система выдает:

```
FileNotFoundException: Template "templates\\page.html" not found
```

В чем же дело?

Спасибо!

Классы в которых возникает exception:

```
public class MirrorRequestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Map<String, Object> pageVariables = createPageVariablesMap(request);

        response.getWriter().println(PageGenerator.instance().getPage("page.html", pageVariables)); // падает здесь

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }


    private static Map<String, Object> createPageVariablesMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> pageVariables = new HashMap<>();
        pageVariables.put("key", request.getParameter("key"));

        return pageVariables;
    }
}



public class PageGenerator {

    private static final String HTML_DIR = "templates";
    private static PageGenerator pageGenerator;
    private final Configuration cfg;

    private PageGenerator() {
        cfg = new Configuration();
    }

    public static PageGenerator instance() {
        if (pageGenerator == null)
            pageGenerator = new PageGenerator();
        return pageGenerator;
    }

    public String getPage(String filename, Map<String, Object> data) {
        Writer stream = new StringWriter();
        try {

            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("classpath:" + HTML_DIR + File.separator + filename); // падает здесь

            template.process(data, stream);
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream.toString();
    }

}
```

Весь pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>L1.1</groupId>
    <artifactId>L1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Maven JAR Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!--<classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>-->
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>


            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>templates/*.html</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>


    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MirrorRequestServlet mirrorRequestServlet = new MirrorRequestServlet();

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(mirrorRequestServlet), "/mirror");

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(context);

        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started");

        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведи полный стектрейс исключения и что за переменная `cfg`?

Comment: `private final Configuration cfg;`


Задание проверяется с помощью другого джарника, вот вывод в коммандной строке (тут такой слеш -  / , это я экспериментировал)

http://cs629126.vk.me/v629126993/2384b/NPUxyK0LyKY.jpg

Comment: Картинки ссылками выкладывать не надо. Плюс, уточнения к заданию стоит делать редактированием исходного вопроса, и помечать их абзацем, начинающимся с **UPDATEXX**

Comment: Что значит в `jar`? У тебя же сервлет, то есть должен быть `war`. Freemarker рекомендует не использовать системный сепаратор, поэтому стоит использовать `/` вместо `File.separator`. Конфигурирование при помощи указанного метода тоже не помогает?

Comment: добавь исходник класса `main.Main`

Comment: добавил и мэйн тоже

Comment: Сервер не откликается вообще (какой результат при запуске http://localhost:8080/mirror) или падает при запросе? Собственно это тема отдельного вопроса. Создавай его с темой "Не работает встроенный в jar jetty" и вываливай туда свой вопрос с контентом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй

```
 Template template = cfg.getTemplate("classpath:"+HTML_DIR + File.separator + filename);
```

Или при создании сконфигурируй свой `cfg` при помощи метода [setClassForTemplateLoading(Class resourceLoaderClass,String basePackagePath)](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setClassForTemplateLoading-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "classpath:templates\\page.html" not found.`

Без `classpath:` (как я раньше делал) приложение запускается и корректно отрабатывает из ИДЕА. Проблемы начинаются в джаре.

Comment: `Инструкция подготовки к локальной проверке:`
`Соберите сервер со всеми зависимостями на библиотеки в `server.jar`
`Для этого запустите Maven projects/<Project` `name>/Plugins/assembly/assembly:single`
`либо assembly.sh (assembly.bat)`

`Скопируйте server.jar на уровень src и запустите`
`java -jar server.jar`

Я начинающий, поэтому делаю пока что говорят в задании)

Comment: @АлександрДворцов теперь всё стало на свои имена. Плагин, который ты используешь для сборки `всё в один jar` очень пакостный. Приведи полный `pom.xml`, структуру проекта (достаточно скриншота с развернутыми папками) и полный код класса в котором падает исключение. Тогда станет ясно как привести твой проект к возможности запуска из локали.

Comment: делал так:

 `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(),`
  `                  "classpath:");`
   `         Template template = cfg.getTemplate(HTML_DIR + `File.separator + filename);`

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "templates\\page.html" not found.`

Comment: @АлександрДворцов надо использовать `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/"+HTML_DIR)` и тогда загружать его  `cfg.getTemplate(filename)`

Comment: Теперь видит вьюху!
Но выводит вот что:
https://ucarecdn.com/93ee302f-df27-4b3a-82d8-0970ff47ed4f/